# Android Studio cant run application

Tags: android-studio

I tried to find solution to this problem but I found only change **grandle.options** and it did not work.

Here is error code:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageInstantRunResourcesDebug'.
> Failed to read zip file 'C:\Users\Admin\AndroidStudioProjects\AppName\app\build\intermediates\instant-run-resources\resources-debug.ir.ap_'.
```

Comment: which version of gradle you are using?

Comment: Grandle version 4.1